# Xamarin Forms Wait for image to be saved and show it

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, xamarin.ios, skiasharp

I have a problem. I have a skiasharp which I convert to a png when I click a button.
Here is the code for that:

```
async void OnButtonClicked(object sender, EventArgs args)
{
    using (var image = args.Surface.Snapshot())
    using (var data = image.Encode(SKEncodedImageFormat.Png, 80))
    using (var stream = File.OpenWrite(Path.Combine("MyApp.TempImages", "1.png")))
    {
        data.SaveTo(stream);
    }
}
```

But now I actually want to go to the next page. That page contains a Image where I want to show the saved image. First I created a ActivityIndicator like this on that page:

```
<ActivityIndicator Color="Red" IsRunning="true" />
```

So I want that to be shown while the image is loading.
The problem is that I don't know how to check wheter the image has been saved, so I can assign it to the source of the Image on that page and remove the ActivityIndicator. Also, I want to run the image saving on a background thread, so I don't have to wait before it saves.

Does anyone have an idea how I can do that?

Comment: use File.Exists to see if the file has been created

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using `data.SaveTo(stream)` I would probably use `data.AsStream()` and use the async methods in that stream to copy it to the `FileStream`. This way you can toggle the visibility of your `ActivityIndicator` before and after that operation. So something like:

```
async void OnButtonClicked(object sender, EventArgs args)
{
    // Show ActivityIndicator here

    using (var image = args.Surface.Snapshot())
    using (var data = image.Encode(SKEncodedImageFormat.Png, 80))
    using (var stream = File.OpenWrite(Path.Combine("MyApp.TempImages", "1.png")))
    {
        var dataStream = data.AsStream();
        await dataStream.CopyTo(stream);
        await stream.FlushAsync();
    }

    // Hide ActivityIndicator here
}
```

If you give your `ActivityIndicator` a name `x:Name="Indicator"`, you can use that to show/hide it.

If you want to wait navigating before the file is saved, just do that instead of showing/hiding the indicator.

Comment: Okay, but the ActivityIndicator is on the next page. So what code do I need to add there to check if the task of saving the image is done?

Comment: I would wait with navigating at all. Or move the task of saving the image to somewhere, which is not the page it self, so it can continue running in the background while you are doing other things in the App. However, is this saving of image operation so long that you need to show an ActivityIndicator?

Comment: I have no idea, but I thought it was user friendly?